# Can proteins structure change depending of alimentation of an organism?

Tags: proteins, gene-expression

In my understanding protein are built using information caring by RNA. So a given protein should always have the same structure in a given organism has the DNA of this organism does not change.

I'm asking this question because peoples told me that "cow milk protein become longer because how we feed them today". But I don't understand how a protein can become longer or shorter.

Info: I have no background in biology. I do not try to solve a problem, but simply have a better understanding.

Comment: Hi gagarine, to me, for this question to be reopened it would at least require a more solid basis than "people told me". So, if you can cite some paper or news report or something like that at a minimum, it could direct someone to what exactly your question is about versus what is getting transformed between what you heard and what you translated that to write in your question (like a game of [telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers)).

Comment: @BryanKrause thanks for the pointer. Jill Hoyt mentioned it was a hot topic in the 90s, and certainly taken in the mainstream, there is a bit of history there and "legend". Removing altogether the "people told me" part would be ok also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is theoretically possible for a protein to change size (based on length) because of nutrition, I don't think that's happening here.

You are right-- DNA encodes information that is transcribed to RNA which is translated into proteins. Proteins are made of a finite number of amino acids, which are the building blocks of proteins. Proteins can be modified (and can be cleaved to make the protein shorter), but I think this claim of "cow milk protein becomes longer" is a misunderstanding because there is not a single "cow milk protein", but rather many.

There are many different proteins in cow milk, and most of them are casein proteins. [source](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/51/1/37.short)

The milk protein likely at the root of this claim is beta-casein. It was a hot topic in the 1990s, because there are a dozen different variants of this beta-casein protein. Two of these variants are the most common in milk have been studied a lot: variant A1 and A2. The only way these are different is a single amino acid change at amino acid position 67 (remember that proteins are made of amino acids). Variant A1 has a histidine amino acid but variant A2 has a proline. What does that mean? That means that A1 can be cut (in your body) to produce a smaller protein bit (called a peptide). Because of the proline in the A2 variant, it cannot be cut like the A1 variant. The peptide resulting from the A1 getting cut is called BCM7.

In short:
beta-casein variant A1: can be cut to produce BCM7
beta-caesin variant A2: gets cut way less than A1 so way less BCM7 is produced.

So, what is BCM7? It had been reported to been linked to some different diseases but the European Food Safety Authority (EFSA) published [this report](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.2903/j.efsa.2009.231r/epdf) which concludes that there is no link between BCM7 and non-communicable diseases. Despite this, there is still a lot of talk about A1 vs A2 in the dairy community. While websites such as [this](http://www.snowvillecreamery.com/a1-and-a2-beta-casein-in-cow-milk.html) appear compelling, remember the EFSA report!

[this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4487594/) is open source and has the information about these variants that is summarized above.

So what does all this have to do with "cow milk protein" changing size? Maybe more cows used as dairy cows have the A2 variant, which would not produce as much BCM7 (the small peptide). Since A2 is not cleaved to produce BCM7, it could be thought of as "longer"... at least relative to only a few thousand years ago. 
The beta-casein A2 variant is thought to be the original version of beta-casein from undomesticated cows.

So, if this claim was originally about beta-casein, you can respond that "yes, the beta-casein protein can be thought of longer because it is not cut to produce the BCM7 peptide as much as the A1 variant is, but it is also the original beta-casein size." Whether it was 10,000 years ago or just now, the A2 beta-casein variant is the same size.

tl;dr / Good reading from the [California Dairy Research Foundation](http://cdrf.org/2017/02/09/a2-milk-facts/).

Comment: Variation of components in milk related to different factors. Again, it's not about changing the protein structure depending of alimentation. https://extension.psu.edu/milk-components-understanding-milk-fat-and-protein-variation-in-your-dairy-herd